# Page loads with navbar extended - already checked for "collapse in"

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Anyone know why my page is loading with the navbar pre toggled down by looking at this code?

The navbar loads extended, but then a click on the toggle button "refreshes" it into the extended position. A second click then retracts the navbar to the position I would like it initialized in.

```
<div class="nav-gradient">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div>
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-right-matt">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="/websites/view/high-end-price" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><?=_('Websites')?><b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class of collapse to your `.navbar-collapse` like so:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```